# How to unit test react components which are part of nested react routes

Tags: routes, react-router, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

My component chain looks like below

[image]

My requirement here is to test Sidebar and MainBar components. And MainBar has routes in it.

Am using enzyme.Mount and I see it never renders the sideBar component

```
 const AppWrapper = enzyme.mount(
      <IntlProvider locale="en">
        <SideBar />
      </IntlProvider>
    );
```

expect(AppWrapper.find(Nav)).toBe(true);//It fails , it never finds the Nav.

**Question** : How to render SideBar which is part of route (:apps/teamsAppId) using enzyme.mount?

Note : Am using react-router-dom hooks

Comment: Do you have Nav when logging console.log(AppWrapper.debug())

Answer (score 0):

First of all, enzyme's `find()` returns a collection of dom nodes. So what you're actually doing is checking if a collection is true.

Try this instead:
`expect(AppWrapper.contains(Nav)).toBe(true);`

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Well, I actually need this to work expect(AppWrapper.find(Nav).props().groups?.length).toBe(3); I cannot achieve this using "Contains". Right now, It says TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined, It fails near "useParams" which am using inside SideBar component

Comment: Ok, so I guess there is some conditional rendering in your `SideBar`. Can you please post it's contents?